# minecraft Command Block kill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im the admin on a server and want to make a command block that turns it to day, but also have it that if anyone else right clicks on it, it kills them?

Comment: Are the other players also admins?

Answer (score 1):

Add a repeat command set to always active with the command:

```
execute as @p[distance=0..8,name=!Tyler Hawkins] at @s run kill @s
```

And change "Tyler Hawkins" to your in game nickname

This will kill anyone that gets close to that command block, except you.

Answer (score -1):

Hide the day night command block somewhere, then make a different command block that has the command `/kill @p`

Comment: It does work in Java edition.

Comment: If you do /kill @p, you will kill the closest player, regardless of distance. That means it will kill everyone, one by one.